# How can I use file share links in Markdown?

Tags: html, github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I tried both the regular link syntax for markdown as well as the HTML syntax:

**Anchor:**

```
<a href="file://someserver/wasd/Default.htm">Some Link to File Share</a>
```

*Result:* Some Link to File Share

**Markdown:**

```
[Some Link to File Share](file://someserver/wasd/Default.htm)
```

*Result:* Some Link to File Share

The markdown preview in Atom and VSCode both display the links as I intend them to look like. But once I push, I will have the same non-link plain text as in the example above.

> **Is it simply impossible to do this? If not, can someone please provide a solution?**

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, it is not supported and will not be in the future

- https://github.com/github/markup/issues/426
- https://github.com/github/markup/issues/202

Answer (score -4):

```
[file link](http://example.com)
```

Should only be a link